# How to check for a language of balanced delimiters

Tags: python

I would like to detect a delimiter in a string using Python. After searching a bit, I know i need to import/use csv module but it works for comma-separated files or words. How do i change it to detect any custom-delimiter? Need some help on it. I have attached the question below.

The question for my homework is:

> Write a function to determine if a text has balanced delimiters. The pairs of valid delimiters are (), [], {}, and <>. They may be nested. In addition, determine that text delimiters ' and " are properly matched.

Comment: you gotta have some clue about the possible delimiters, you can't detect any delimiter because virtually anything can be used...

Comment: `reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='|') # pipe delimited`

Comment: What do you mean by "detect a delimiter"? Guess what character is being used as a delimiter? Given a delimiter, see if a string contains it? Split a string on a delimiter?

Comment: Your homework? :S You should solve your homework, not ask someone to solve your homework. In any case, your homework is about the logic involved to solve that problem, not to use another function that has the logic. csv also won't detect nested delimiters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`csv` is not going to help you for this.

This question is asking you to create a function which can detect balanced delimiters - i.e. for every opening delimiter, there is a corresponding closing delimiter.

This is a classic question because it can be specified with a context free grammar, which is equivalent to a statemachine whose edges correspond to the next input, and the nodes specify operations on a stack.

The `list` and `deque` classes make excellent stacks.

Your code should look like:

```
def balancedq(input):
    stack = []

    for char in input:
        #implement your logic here.
        if sometest:
           stack.append(char) #push
        elif someothertest:
           val = stack.pop()
           #maybe some test here?
```